# ssh connection inside a ssh connection: "read PEM private key done: type <unknown>" error

Tags: bash, batch-file, ssh, centos

I am looking for some helps, pointers to documentation or to contacts.

**Context of issue environment**: a MS Windows 7 workstation has to execute a homemade bash script on a CentOS 6.5 server. This is done by a homemade MS batch script using installed OpenSSH client.

The called bash script opens a SSH connection to other CentOS 6.5 server and executes the command

```
ssh userLogin@remoteClient "pidof gnome-panel"
```

This script works fine if it is executed from server X11 environment (yes, this server has the X11 environment). However, when it is executed from Windows by the batch script, the SSH subcommand of "pidof gnome-panel" is blocked. I executed using SSH option "-vvv" (EDIT: complete log)

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/userLogin/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for remoteClient
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remoteClient [209.0.0.63] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
debug1: identity file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 143/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
Warning: Permanently added 'remoteclient,209.0.0.63' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 544/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x21933e0)
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 209.0.0.63.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp f1:80:80:b0:8b:2c:26:a4:ea:4f:73:c0:28:bc:cc:88:10:b1:d0:2b
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA f1:80:80:b0:8b:2c:26:a4:ea:4f:73:c0:28:bc:cc:88:10:b1:d0:2b
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
```

OK log:

```
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/userLogin/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for remoteClient
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remoteClient [209.0.0.63] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
debug1: identity file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: identity file /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 960 bytes for a total of 981
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 1005
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 125/256
debug2: bits set: 537/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 1149
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host remoteclient filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /dev/null
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 209.0.0.63 filename /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
Warning: Permanently added 'remoteclient,209.0.0.63' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug2: bits set: 492/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1165
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 48 bytes for a total of 1213
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x1c5e3e0)
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 1277
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-keyex
debug3: remaining preferred: gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-keyex
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 209.0.0.63.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Credentials cache file '/tmp/krb5cc_500' not found

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/userLogin/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 368 bytes for a total of 1645
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp f1:80:80:b0:8b:2c:26:a4:ea:4f:73:c0:28:bc:cc:88:10:b1:d0:2b
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA f1:80:80:b0:8b:2c:26:a4:ea:4f:73:c0:28:bc:cc:88:10:b1:d0:2b
debug3: Wrote 640 bytes for a total of 2285
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug3: Wrote 128 bytes for a total of 2413
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list displayTMC:0.0 2>/dev/null
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 0
debug3: Wrote 112 bytes for a total of 2525
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_THREAD_MEMORY_SIZE
debug3: Ignored env ORBIT_SOCKETDIR
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_ATT_TIMEOUT_READY_MODE
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_PRIV_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_REFRESH_PEER_MODE
debug3: Ignored env HOSTNAME
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_ENCRYPT_PASS_PHRASE
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_TIMEOUT_SWITCH_OPER_EVAL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env HISTSIZE
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_AUTH_TYPE
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NB_SEC_STANDBY_STARTUP
debug3: Ignored env GTK_RC_FILES
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env TRACE_TEMPS
debug3: Ignored env QTDIR
debug3: Ignored env QTINC
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_UDP_BUFFER_SIZE
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LD_LIBRARY_PATH
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_INSTALLATION_MODE
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_OPEREVAL_ACTIVATION
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_TRAINING_REINITIALIZE_TIMEOUT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_KEYRING_SOCKET
debug3: Ignored env TERMCAP
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NB_ATT_STANDBY_STARTUP
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env USERNAME
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_PERIOD_OF_CHECK_READY_MODE
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_COMMUNITY
debug3: Ignored env GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NETPRI
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_CHECK_ENVIRONMENT_LEVEL
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_HUNTER_PROCESS_PERIOD
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NB_FLOATING_IP_CHECK
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env STY
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env GDM_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env KDE_IS_PRELINKED
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_MODE_STANDBY_PERIODIC_CHECK
debug3: Ignored env GDM_LANG
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_SECURITY_LEVEL
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NB_PERSISTENCY_CHECK
debug3: Ignored env KDEDIRS
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_STANDBY_PERIODIC_PERSISTENCY_CHECK
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_ATT_TIMEOUT_PERSISTENCY_CHECK
debug3: Ignored env GDMSESSION
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_LOCALE
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_REASON_OF_WAIT
debug3: Ignored env HISTCONTROL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_ASKPASS
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_HOME
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_ADAPTER_INTERNAL_NETWORK
debug3: Ignored env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TARGET_CLUSTER_STATUS_AFTER_SWITCH
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env CVS_RSH
debug3: Ignored env QTLIB
debug3: Ignored env WINDOW
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_SNMP_TRAPVERSION
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env PROMPT_COMMAND
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_CC_LOG_PATH
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_NETSEC
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_KILLER_PROCESS_PERIOD
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_AUTH_PASS_PHRASE
debug3: Ignored env SNMP_SECURITY_NAME
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_UDP_MULTICAST_TTL
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_CC_MAINMENU_FILENAME
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_CC_CUSTOM_SCRIPTS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env userLogin_CC_MENUS_PATH
debug3: Ignored env G_BROKEN_FILENAMES
debug3: Ignored env XAUTHORITY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug1: Sending command: /sbin/pidof gnome-panel
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: Wrote 144 bytes for a total of 2669
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
2409
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r -1 w -1 e 6 c -1
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 2701
debug3: Wrote 64 bytes for a total of 2765
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 2 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2568, received 2368 bytes, in 0.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 44382.9, received 40926.3
debug1: Exit status 0
```

I compared these captured logs but I did not note explanation of observed behaviour; the differences of logs:

```
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 143/256
debug2: bits set: 508/1024
debug2: bits set: 544/1024
debug2: key: /home/snet/.ssh/id_rsa.pub (0x21933e0)
```

where 143, 508, 544 and 0x21933e0 are different.

I absolutely does not understand why in this environment, the SSH connection is blocked...

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you. Best regards,

EDIT: the used private RSA key is not encrypted and ssh-agent is down. 
EDIT: the content of userLogin/.ssh/config file

```
Host remoteClient
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

EDIT: the SELinux config

```
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

CLOSED: FYI, the issued server has been reinstalled without a fix. after re-installation, it works fine :(

Comment: What is the command you ran? What your configuration?

Comment: Hi @Jakuje, Thank you for your interest to my problem. The first SSH connection executes a bash script. This bash script executes the command `ssh user_login@remoteClientIP pidof gnome-panel` The conf of ws workstation is Windows 7 64-bits. The conf of Linux stations is CentOS 6.5 32 bit

Comment: What script? What command? What arguments. I see only the logs, but no command.

Comment: Home-made bash script which checks some local configuration and executes `ssh user@remote pidof gnome-panel` command. This ssh command is blocked

Comment: Well ... the private key is encrypted and in your X sessions you have `ssh-agent` running which has the decrypted pem key.

Comment: the private key is not encrypted and ssh-agent is not running.

Comment: Please, provide complete logs. It is not clear from the snippets where all is the difference.

Comment: I added complete log to initial description. @Jakuje, thank for your time

Comment: What do you have in `/home/userLogin/.ssh/config`?

Comment: added to description

Comment: What about SELinux? Is it in enforcing mode? Do you have any AVCs?

Comment: SELinux Config:
`SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted`